# Trying to redirect from domain.com/user/12345 to domain.com/user?id=12345

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect from `domain.com/user/12345` to `domain.com/user?id=12345` and from `domain.com/user/12345/profile` to `domain.com/user/profile?id=12345`.

I've written this rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]*)(/.*)?$ user$2?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works ok for `domain.com/user/12345/profile` but `domain.com/user/12345` is not redirected.

I've also tried with this simplest form for this case:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]*)$ user?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've tested both in http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and seems to work fine.

¿What is my mistake? ¿How can I do it?

**UPDATE:**

The next rule I've in this file rewrites from `domain.com/user` to `domain.com/user.php` and so on. If the previous rule is not defined it rewrites ok from `domain.com/user/12345` to `domain.com/user/12345.php` but with the previous rule defined it neither does this rewriting.

Does it means that there is any kind or transformation that skip the second rule or that there is any kind of misyake that stops rules verification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I don't know why it worked well in a case and not in the other but I'd forgotten the slash so it was trying to rewrite to `user?id=12345`and not to `/user?id=12345`.

So the rule must be like this one:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]*)(/.*)?$ /user$2?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```